# How to substract two dates resulting in days or weeks?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm looking for a function in which I can enter 2 dates:

Starting like this:

```
         public static String getDaysOrWeeksFromDateDiff(DateTime first, DateTime second)
        {
    //this function will substract the date from the other and result days if < 8 and weeks if > 7

return "1 week";
        }
```

I've tried this function below, but it gives me a negative date (I've missed the year somehow in the calculation)

```
 public static String getDaysOrWeeksFromDateDiff(DateTime first, DateTime second)
    {
        var cal = new GregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendarTypes.Localized);
        var weeknr = cal.GetWeekOfYear(first, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        var weeknr2 = cal.GetWeekOfYear(second, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        String strReturnValue;
        if (weeknr == weeknr2)
        {
            var dagen = first.Day - second.Day;
            strReturnValue = (dagen == 0 ? "today" : (dagen == 1 ? "1 day" : dagen + " days"));
        }
        else
        {
            strReturnValue = (weeknr - weeknr2 == 1 ? "1 week" : weeknr - weeknr2 + " weeks");
        }
        return strReturnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [subtract dates directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx):

```
TimeSpan difference = second - first;
```

This returns a [*TimeSpan* object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx), which you can query easily, e.g.

```
if (difference.Days >= 8) ...
```

Converting the number of `Days` into weeks should be a trivial exercise since every week has exactly 7 days...

(Note that [`Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) will give you the number of days as an integer, whereas [`TotalDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will include fractional days.)

Comment: You should use `Math.Abs(difference.Days)` if you don't care if `first` > `second` and you don't want a negative result.

Comment: @DominicKexel I do need indeed just the difference between both Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Time span class

```
    public static String getWeekOrMonthFromDateDiff(DateTime first, DateTime second)
    {
        var span = second - first;
        if (span.Days <= 7)
            return span.Days + " day(s)";
        else
            return span.Days / 7 + " week(s)"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
TimeSpan diff = first - second;
```

Then you can do

```
int weekCount = diff.TotalDays / 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this some days ago:

```
private string GetTimeSpan(DateTime toDateTime, DateTime fromDateTime)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = toDateTime- fromDateTime;

        if (ts.Days < 0)
        {
            return "since " + ts.Days.ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty) + " Days";
        }
        else if (ts.Hours < 1)
        {
            return "in " + ts.Minutes + " Minutes";
        }
        else if (ts.Days < 1)
        {
            return "in " + ts.Hours + " Hours";
        }
        else if (ts.Days < 7)
        {
            return "in " + ts.Days + " Days";
        }
        else
        {
            return "in " + ts.Days / 7 + " Weeks";
        }
    }
```

Modify it the way you Need it :)

Comment: `if (ts.Days < 0)` is this ever evaluates to true? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have to remove a lot if I take this, but I see the essential part.

Comment: Yes this could be true. In my case it is for appointments. If a appointment is in past, ts.Days < 0 is true. Thats why the return value is "since" ;)

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Yes. If `fromDateTime` is greater than `toDateTime`, then   `ts.Days` will be negative

Comment: @Relax well, this assumption makes other branches invalid.

Answer (score 1):

For a length of time like this, you should use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`, and then calculate the number of weeks from the property `TotalDays`.

Answer (score -1):

```
void func(DateTime t1, DateTime t2)
{
    days = (t2 - t1).TotalDays;
    weeks = days/7;
    year = weeks/52;
}
```